# book appointment functionality

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have Django project, which contains two classes in model.py file, one is clinic(which has a contact number as a field) and other one is patient. I have rendered all the clinics in cards and each card has a button book-appointment.

here is my model.py:

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    clinic_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, verbose_name='Name')
    poster = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d', verbose_name='Picture')
    address = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank= True)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, verbose_name='Mobile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.clinic_name

class Patient(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    appointment_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient_name
```

Now what I want is, when a authentic user which is patient in this case, clicks on book-appointment , A message should be sent on the clinics phone number saying this guys have booked an appointment with you on this date.

how this can be achieved??? please guide me.

Comment: You mean like a SMS ? If that's the case, you should look into the package `django-sms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models:

```
from django import models

class Appointment(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='appointments')
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='appointments')
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.clinic} - {self.patient} - {self.time}'
```

Forms:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Appointment

class AppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('clinic', 'time',)
```

Urls:

```
from .views import book_appointment_view

app_name = '<appname>'
path('book-appointment/', book_appointment_view, name='book-appointment')
```

Views:

```
from django.urls import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest

@login_required
def book_appointment_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST or None)
        user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.instance.patient = user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Appointment booked {form.instance.patient.patient_name} !')
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        HttpResponseBadRequest('You can not do that')
```

Html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url '<appname>:book-appointment' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

As far as SMS goes, check out [django-twillio](https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-twilio) for sms. I've heard good things.

Comment: Thank you so much @beasyx ! I have checked this twillio and I am able to send msg to a number now i just need to make it dynamic.